# Can anyone help to get rid of this infinity-infinity?

Tags: limits

How does one get rid of the infinities arising here?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln|x-1|}3-\frac{\ln|x+2|}3\right)$$

I really have no idea how to handle such natural logarithms.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply the rules of logarithm to get:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\log|x-1|}{3} - \frac{\log|x+2|}{3} &= \frac{1}{3}(\log|x-1| - \log|x +2|) \\&= \frac{1}{3}\log\left|\frac{x-1}{x+2}\right|\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\log\left|\frac{1-\frac{1}{x}}{1 + \frac{2}{x}}\right|\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle\ln a-\ln b=\ln (a/b)$

$$\ln|x-1|-\ln|x+2|=\ln\left|\frac{x-1}{x+2}\right|=\ln\left|\frac{1-1/x}{1+2/x}\right|$$